# Angular Animations : How to bind animation trigger name dynamically in the template?

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-animations

I would like to know if there is a way to bind the animation trigger name dynamically in the template.

Here is the div to animate in the template **app.component.html**:

```
<div [@animationTriggerName]>
  ...
</div>
```

Here is the **app.module.ts**:

```
...
@NgModule({
  imports:      [...],
  declarations: [ ..., AnimationTriggerNameDirective ],
  bootstrap:    [...]
})
```

And here is the **app.component.ts**:

```
@Component({
  ...
})
export class AppComponent  {
  ...
  animationTriggerName = 'slideInOut';
}

@Directive({
  selector: '[animationTriggerName]'
})
export class AnimationTriggerNameDirective {
  @Input() animationTriggerName: string;
  constructor() {}
}
```

I want to be able to set the variable *animationTriggerName* dynamically.
So if I set it to *myTriggerName*, then in the template I would have this rendered :

```
<div [@myTriggerName]>
  ...
</div>
```

And so the animation whose trigger name is *myTriggerName* would be able to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after I learn from this post. it looks like use multiple states is much eaiser than using trigger name, so I change my code structure  like below, below is the original post for your reference https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/hammerjs-angular-5-animations-for-mobile-gestures-tutorial/

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hammer-card',
  templateUrl: './hammer-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hammer-card.component.sass'],
  animations: [
    trigger('cardAnimator', [
      transition('* => wobble', animate(1000, keyframes(kf.wobble))),
      transition('* => swing', animate(1000, keyframes(kf.swing))),
      transition('* => jello', animate(1000, keyframes(kf.jello))),
      transition('* => zoomOutRight', animate(1000, keyframes(kf.zoomOutRight))),
      transition('* => slideOutLeft', animate(1000, keyframes(kf.slideOutLeft))),
      transition('* => rotateOutUpRight', animate(1000, keyframes(kf.rotateOutUpRight))),
      transition('* => flipOutY', animate(1000, keyframes(kf.flipOutY))),
    ])
  ]
})
```

Comment: I find this approach works best for me too ~ instead of putting multiple triggers in one component, put them all under one parent trigger, and split by states. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I have similar issues like the posted question, so far I use ngSwitch and ngSwitchCase as workaround as I fail to do the varaible binding after some try anderror. I don't think below example is the optimal solution, as it will be tedious if I want to switch the trigger name to hundred, however it works for me now, to change the trigger name in run time, hope there is some other better idea, and hope it helps

```
<div [ngSwitch]="child.animationName" >
 <input *ngSwitchCase="flyInOut" [@flyInOut]="'in'"  ...>
 <input *ngSwitchCase="fadeIn" [@fadeIn]="'in'"  ...> 
 <input *ngSwitchDefault [@flyRotateInOut]="'in'" ...>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a really good workaround, but it can be a problem for big <div> to have the code duplicated just to change the animation name. I will wait to accept the answer to see if there is another idea

Comment: Hi, After I learned from below URL, it should be much better to use multiple 'states' ,not to use the multiple trigger names to make code more complex https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/hammerjs-angular-5-animations-for-mobile-gestures-tutorial/