# In angular, how to give animation trigger which is dependent on some condition

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-animations

```
<div [@fade]="state" (@fade.done)="animationDone($event)"></div>
```

How can 'fade' trigger be replaced by any other animation trigger. On some condition 'fade' can be 'slide'.

Comment: I think this is the same question : https://stackoverflow.com/q/47365594/8800147